# do i have to use the php configure command?

Tags: php, linux

when installing php from source, do i have to add all the ./configure options?
or can i just use ./configure and then edit the php.ini?

Answer (score 2):

Some modules won't get built if you don't specify them explicitly at the `./configure` stage. No amount of php.ini changes later on will magically make the modules' .so files appear, meaning you'd have to recompile to activate them.

Answer (score 1):

If you are installing PHP with Apache2 the bare minimum is:

`./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apx`

Adding additional options will add additional modules to PHP. For instance, if you want MySQL support you need to add `--with-mysql`.

You can checkout the other available options by typing `./configure --help`

More information about installing PHP here: https://www.php.net/install

Hope this helps!

- Christian

Comment: if want add ./configure --with-mysql, do I need to recompile, and call the make command again? what is the step?

Answer (score 0):

Just carefully read the README file. Try to avoid modifications to the php.ini as usually this is allowed to the system admins only.